# I want to pass LWC button value, set by xml propert api item to a javascript method to navigate to internal pages, help pass page to navigationmixin!

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript

HTML:

```
<!-- sldsValidatorIgnore -->
<template>
    <div class="bounding">
        <div class="slds-grid slds-gutters slds-m-around_large ">
            <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-3 slds-m-around_xx-small box">
                <img src={img1} alt="Image 1">
                <h1>{top1}</h1>
                <h3>{sub1}</h3>

            </div>
            <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-3 slds-m-around_xx-small box">
                <img src={img2} alt="Image 2">
                <h1>{top2}</h1>
                <h3>{sub2}</h3>

            </div>
            <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-3 slds-m-around_xx-small box">
                <img src={img3} alt="Image 3">
                <h1>{top3}</h1>
                <h3>{sub3}</h3>

            </div>

        </div>
        <div class="slds-grid slds-gutters slds-m-around_xx-small">
            <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-1">
                <br>
                <a href="#" onclick={handleButtonClick}>
                    <button class="slds-button slds-button_brand">{butLab}</button>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

JS:

```
import { LightningElement, api } from 'lwc';
import { NavigationMixin } from 'lightning/navigation';

export default class ThreeColumnTile extends NavigationMixin(LightningElement) {
  @api image1;
  @api image2;
  @api image3;
  @api topic1;
  @api topic2;
  @api topic3;
  @api subtopic1;
  @api subtopic2;
  @api subtopic3;
  @api buttonLabel;
  @api internalPageApiName;

  get img1(){
    return this.image1;
  }

  get img2(){
    return this.image2;
  }

  get img3(){
    return this.image3;
  }

  get top1(){
    return this.topic1;
  }

  get top2(){
    return this.topic2;
  }

  get top3(){
    return this.topic3;
  }

  get sub1(){
    return this.subtopic1;
  }

  get sub2(){
    return this.subtopic2;
  }

  get sub3(){
    return this.subtopic3;
  }

  get butLab(){
    return this.buttonLabel;
  }

  handleButtonClick(){
    this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({
      type:'comm__namedPage',
      attributes:{
        name: internalPageApiName
      }
    });
  }


}
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LightningComponentBundle xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <apiVersion>56.0</apiVersion>
    <isExposed>true</isExposed>
    <targets>
        <target>lightning__RecordPage</target>
        <target>lightning__AppPage</target>
        <target>lightning__HomePage</target>
        <!--<target>lightning__Tab</target>-->
        <!--<target>lightning__RecordAction</target>-->
        <!--<target>lightning__Inbox</target>-->
        <!--<target>lightning__UtilityBar</target>-->
        <!--<target>lightning__FlowScreen</target>-->
        <!--<target>lightningSnapin__ChatMessage</target>-->
        <!--<target>lightningSnapin__Minimized</target>-->
        <!--<target>lightningSnapin__PreChat</target>-->
        <!--<target>lightningSnapin__ChatHeader</target>-->
        <target>lightningCommunity__Page</target>
        <target>lightningCommunity__Default</target>
        <!--<target>lightningCommunity__Page_Layout</target>-->
        <!--<target>lightningCommunity__Theme_Layout</target>-->
    </targets>
    <targetConfigs>
        <targetConfig targets="lightningCommunity__Default">
            <property name="image1" type="String" label="Image 1 URL" description="Paste the image URL" default="https://i.postimg.cc/Gpnz3mXc/blog_placeholder.jpg"/>

            <property name="topic1" type="String" label="Topic 1" 
            description="Enter a topic..." default="Topic One goes here."/>

            <property name="subtopic1" type="String" label="Subtopic One Content"
            description="Type a subtopic or some content" default="Subtopic content gores here..."/>


            <property name="image2" type="String" label="Image 2 URL" description="Paste the image URL" default="https://i.postimg.cc/Gpnz3mXc/blog_placeholder.jpg"/>
            
            <property name="topic2" type="String" label="Topic 2" 
            description="Enter a topic..." default="Topic Two goes here."/>

            <property name="subtopic2" type="String" label="Subtopic Two Content"
            description="Type a subtopic or some content" default="Subtopic content gores here..."/>



            <property name="image3" type="String" label="Image 3 URL" description="Paste the image URL" default="https://i.postimg.cc/Gpnz3mXc/blog_placeholder.jpg"/>
            
            <property name="topic3" type="String" label="Topic 3" 
            description="Enter a topic..." default="Topic Three goes here."/>

            <property name="subtopic3" type="String" label="Subtopic Three Content"
            description="Type a subtopic or some content" default="Subtopic content gores here..."/>

            <property name="buttonLabel" type="String" label="Action Button"
            description="Type the button action label" default="Lets Go"/>

            <property name="internalPageApiName" type="String" label="Page API name"
            description="Check the api name of the site page and type or paste" default="estate__c"/>
        </targetConfig>
    </targetConfigs>
</LightningComponentBundle>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

did you try with state attribute like below

```
handleButtonClick(){
this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({
  type:'comm__namedPage',
  attributes:{
    name: internalPageApiName
  },
  state: {
    c__subtopic2: this.subtopic2
        }
});
}
```

and in `internalPageApiName` page component you should use @wire pagereference  like below

```
@wire(CurrentPageReference)
getPageref(currentPageRef) {
if (currentPageRef) {
   this.nsubtopic2 = currentPageRef.state?.c__subtopic2;
 }
}
```

Comment: thank you for this, apparently i needed to add this.variable name. changed the type to standard webpage and use url instead of api name and it now works like a charm. thank you.